# Running rails test creates two new databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I run `rails test`, it creates two new test database in Postgres - `example_test-0` and `example_test-1`, apart from the `example_test` database that already existed. This only happens when I just started using postgres.app on my mac, it never occured to me when I was using homebrew's postgres all this while. Why does that happen and how do I prevent that?

Ps: I decided switched to using postgres.app because I needed to use specifically Postgres 12, with both TimescaleDB and PostGIS extensions enabled and homebrew's postgres is giving me a headache on achieving that.

Comment: Did you also enable parallel testing in your config? The names you mentioned are created for parallel tests by rails. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#parallel-testing

Comment: @Anuj thank you. I just realized that. It must've also been the case all this while when I used homebrew's postgres, I just never 'saw' it